# Loading 30000 documents from wikipedia

Tags: hadoop, wiki, hdfs, mediawiki-api

I have a wikipedia url and I want to load the content from that page and other referenced pages upto 30000 documents using wiki API, I can loop through the urls and do that but that is not an effiecient way of doing it. Is there any other way through which I can acheive this. I need this to populate my HDFS in hadoop.

Comment: I hope you're making a donation to them. Serving up 30,000 pages will cost them some money.

Comment: I'll definately make some donation if I get some smooth way of getting the referenced documents from title page.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the wikimedia software and a database image, set up the wikipedia and access it locally. This is well described and should be a lot more efficient then requesting that number of pages through the net. see: http://www.igeek.co.za/2009/10/16/how-to-mirror-wikipedia/

There are also many other sources and also preprocessed pages. Here comes the question what you plan to do with the content in the next step.

Comment: I don't see why would you need to set up Mediawiki to access its data, the database image is enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go about this. [Toolserver](https://wiki.toolserver.org/view/Main_Page) users have direct database query access to all the metadata, but not text. If that suits you, you might be able to [ask one of them to run a query](https://jira.toolserver.org/browse/DBQ) through the [query service](https://wiki.toolserver.org/view/Query_service). This is a pretty straight-forward way to find out what pages are linked, etc. and build a map of page ids or revision ids.

Otherwise, take a look at [database dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#English-language_Wikipedia) which are great for bulk work but will take some processing on your end.

Finally, Wikipedia is used to tons of bots and [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) scrapes. It's not ideal, but if nothing else suits you then run a timer that starts a new query once every second and you'll be done in 8 hours.

Comment: If you're talking about bots that run on Wikipedia, you should also mention how they do it: using [the API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php).

Answer (score 0):

As it is said by Jeff and NilsB you have a wrong intent to crawl wikipedia for filling your HDFS. The right thing to do it is to download the whole wiki as a single file and to load it to HDFS.

But if we abstracted away from some details in your question it would transform into more general: **How to crawl some sites specified by url using Hadoop?**

So the answer is you should upload the file(s) with url to hdfs, write a mapper (accepting url, downloading a page and yielding it as `key=url` and `value=page's body`) and configure a Job to use [NLineInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html) for controlling the count of url each mapper'll process. 
By control of that parameter you'll be able to control a level of parallelism through itself and the map slots count.